# Split array into size limited CSV strings

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, refactoring

I am looking for an efficient way to convert a large int[] into a string[] of csv strings where each csv is limited to a maximum of 4000 characters. The values in the array could be anything between 1 and int.MaxValue.

Here is my final code:

```
public static string[] GetCSVsFromArray(int[] array, int csvLimit)
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(int id in array)
    {
        string intId = id.ToString();
        if (sb.Length + intId.Length < csvLimit)
            sb.Append(intId).Append(",");
        else
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Length--;
            parts.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Length = 0;
        }
    }
    if(sb.Length>0)
       parts.Add(sb.ToString());
    return parts.ToArray();
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

So here is what I am now using (I was able to change the return parameter to the List type to save the ToArray() call at the end):

```
public static List<string> GetCSVsFromArray(int[] array, int csvLimit)
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(int id in array)
    {
        string intId = id.ToString();
        if (sb.Length + intId.Length < csvLimit)
            sb.Append(intId).Append(",");
        else
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Length--;
            parts.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Length = 0;
        }
    }
    if(sb.Length>0)
       parts.Add(sb.ToString());
    return parts;
}
```

Performance results:

10,000,000 items csv Limit of 4000 characters

- Original: 2,887.488ms
- GetIntegerDigitCount: 3105.355ms
- Final: 2883.587ms

Whilst I only saved 4ms removing the ToArray() call on my developer machine this seems to make a significant difference on a much slower machine (saved over 200ms on a DELL D620)

Comment: You are doing redundant `parts.ToArray()` which doing memory copy for the all items under the hood

Comment: You are throwing away the value of intId when you create a new line?

Comment: Why do I get the impression that you are [rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)? Please don't do that. Don't write such code.

Comment: the csv's are the input parameter (nvarchar(4000)) for a stored procedure that I cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a lot of heap memory allocations when creating a new string for each number just to calculate number of digits. Use [following method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/integer-digit-count) to calculate number of digits in the number (see method below).

So instead of

```
string intId = id.ToString();
if (sb.Length + intId.Length < csvLimit)
```

Just use:

```
if (sb.Length + this.GetIntegerDigitCount(id) < csvLimit)
```

**Results:**

- 2 times faster on 10 million numbers
- Old: 4316ms, New:1983ms, Diff: 2333ms. Faster 217.6%

**EDIT:** More results on large csv limit

> Items:10000000; csvLimit:4000; Old:2091ms, New:1868ms, Diff:223ms
>   faster = 111.937901498929%

---

Code I've used to measure time:

```
 double elapsedOld = 0;
 double elapsedNew = 0;
 int count = 10000000;
 int csvLimit = 4000;
 var items = Enumerable.Range(0, count).ToArray();
 var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 this.GetCsVsFromArray(items, csvLimit);
 watch.Stop();
 elapsedOld = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

 watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 this.GetCsVsFromArrayTuned(items, csvLimit);
 watch.Stop();
 elapsedNew = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
 var stat = String.Format(
     "Items:{0}; csvLimit:{1}; Old:{2}ms, New:{3}ms, Diff:{4}ms faster = {5}%",                
     count,
     csvLimit,
     elapsedOld,
     elapsedNew,
     elapsedOld - elapsedNew,
     elapsedOld * 100 / elapsedNew);
```

---

**GetIntegerDigitCount**:

```
public int GetIntegerDigitCount(int valueInt)
{
    double value = valueInt;
    int sign = 0;
    if (value < 0)
    {
        value = -value;
        sign = 1;
    }

    if (value <= 9)
    {
        return sign + 1;
    }

    if (value <= 99)
    {
        return sign + 2;
    }

    if (value <= 999)
    {
        return sign + 3;
    }

    if (value <= 9999)
    {
        return sign + 4;
    }

    if (value <= 99999)
    {
        return sign + 5;
    }

    if (value <= 999999)
    {
        return sign + 6;
    }

    if (value <= 9999999)
    {
        return sign + 7;
    }

    if (value <= 99999999)
    {
        return sign + 8;
    }

    if (value <= 999999999)
    {
        return sign + 9;
    }

    return sign + 10;
}
```

Comment: The ToString is not just to get the length, sb.Append(Int32) internally does a ToString on the int.  Your code only looks faster because you have a string limit of 4 which means you don't do a ToString on any number > 9999. Set the csvLimit to 4000 and check the results.

Comment: I've tried csvlimit=4000, see EDIT part of my answer, basically stat following: `Items:10000000; csvLimit:4000; Old:2091ms, New:1868ms, Diff:223ms faster = 111.937901498929%`

Comment: Really you are right, on large CSV Limit value difference is pretty small. And thanks for a good point regarding StringBuilder's internal `ToString()` call!

Comment: @JohnHunder : are you improved algorithm somehow? It is really intersting to know what is final solution and what is the difference in the performance. Thanks

Comment: Whilst I found the getintegerdigitcount version to be slightly slower (copying the int to a double seems to be at the root of that) it is a good idea in principle.  Also your comment about removing the ToArray() call was the biggest performance increase I could find.

Comment: @JohnHunter : cool, thanks for letting me know, really ToArray() doing a memory copy under the hood so makes sense, also I would return `IEnumerable<string>` rather than array and in foreach do `yield return` but this can make sense only for special use cases of the method when only part of the items will be requested

Answer (score 1):

Linq here can speed up things a bit. Your code will look something like this after few modifications:

```
    public static string[] GetCSVsFromArray(int[] array, int csvLimit)
    {
        List<string> parts = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string intId in array.Select(id => id.ToString()))
        {
            if (sb.Length + intId.Length < csvLimit)
                sb.Append(intId).Append(",");
            else
            {
                if (sb.Length > 0)
                    sb.Length--; parts.Add(sb.ToString()); sb.Length = 0;
            }
        }
        return parts.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the performance of this everytime i tried it is always slightly slower than my original?

Comment: I didn't. Have you logged any data related to its performance?

Comment: 0-10000000, limit 4000 - Original 1770ms, yours 1843ms;
0-10000000, limit 8000 - Original 1808ms, yours 1855ms;
10000000-20000000, limit 8000 - Original 3971ms, yours 4197ms

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it to optimize it.

Comment: check by replacing foreach statement `foreach (string intId in Enumerable.Select(array, id => id.ToString()))`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;    

public static string[] GetCSVsFromArray(int[] array, int limit)
{
    int i = 0;
    return array.Select(a => a.ToString())
                .GroupBy(a => { i += a.Length; return (i - a.Length) / limit; })
                .Select(a => string.Join(",",a))
                .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: have you tried launching this code? Some performance metrics `Items: 1000000. Old: 404ms, New:1844ms, Diff: -1440ms`, extremely slow. From performance perspectives shorten code snippet is not always faster

Comment: Tell me input array size, please

Comment: See my first comment - Items: 1000000

Comment: Can you try replacing string.join with Aggregate?